# When I use jeecg-boot, I met a problem,it said " multi-statement not allow", how can I solve it

Tags: java, mysql

I use this code

```
<update id="update">
        <foreach collection="views" item="item" separator=";">
            update eye_product_standard
            <set>
                <if test="item.name != null and item.name != ''">
                    name = #{item.sku},
                </if>

                <if test="item.inventory != null">
                    inventory = #{item.inventory},
                </if>

                <if test="item.flag != null">
                    flag = #{item.flag},
                </if>

                <if test="item.price != null">
                    skuPrice = #{item.price}
                </if>
            </set>
            where product_id = #{item.productId} and id = #{item.id}
        </foreach>
    </update>
```

and when I run project, it went wrong

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: sql injection violation, multi-statement not allow : UPDATE eye_product_standard SET name = ?, inventory = ?, flag = ?, SkuPrice = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND id = ?;UPDATE eye_product_standard SET name = ?, inventory = ?, flag = ?, SkuPrice = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND id = ?
### The error may exist in URL [jar:file:/home/jeecg-boot/jeecg-system-start-3.4.3.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jeecg-module-demo-3.4.3.jar!/org/jeecg/modules/demo/eyeserver/mapper/xml/eye_product_viewMapper.xml]
### The error may involve org.jeecg.modules.demo.eyeserver.mapper.eye_product_viewMapper.update
### The error occurred while executing an update
### SQL: UPDATE eye_product_standard SET name = ?, inventory = ?, flag = ?, SkuPrice = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND id = ?;UPDATE eye_product_standard SET name = ?, inventory = ?, flag = ?, SkuPrice = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND id = ?
```

I have try to add '&allowMultiQueries=true' to my `application.yml` but it not work.